create a multilingual website in ASP.Net using Globalization and Localization
i have a website that is arabic but i am trying to make it bilingual. i am trying the globalization and localization method so i added the dropdwon english and arabic and then i added the basepage.vb code and i have finally added the global resources folder with the resources for each language and i changed evrythign static arabic to english. the problem is it's working correctly locally but online it stays arabic no matter what i choose in the dropdown
i have this code in my masterpage:
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguages" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLanguages_SelectedIndexChanged">                    
                    <asp:ListItem Text="arabic" Value="ar" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="english" Value="en-us" />
                </asp:DropDownList>

and this in my masterpage pageload:
 Dim language As String = If(Session("Language"), "ar")
            ddlLanguages.SelectedValue = language

  Protected Sub ddlLanguages_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' Update the session with the selected language
        Session("Language") = ddlLanguages.SelectedValue
        ' Optionally, you can also refresh the page to apply the language change immediately
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
    End Sub

and finally i have a basepage.vb code in the app code folder:
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class basepage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
        Dim language As String = "ar" ' Default to Arabic

        If Session("Language") IsNot Nothing Then
            language = Session("Language").ToString()
        End If

        ' Set the Culture
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo(language)
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo(language)
    End Sub
End Class

i have added the app global resources folder and i changed everything static arabic to resources. it is working locally perfect but online on the actual website it's always arabic . when i switch to english, the dropdwon switch to english but the website is still in arabic what could be the issue ? am i misssing something ? should i add anything to my global asax ?

Yeah, this is a common headache with ASP.NET localization, especially when it works locally but not in production. I've run into this a few times before.
From what I see in your code, I think the main issue is that we need more robust language persistence. Right now you're relying solely on Session, which can be finicky in production environments - especially if you have load balancers or if the app pool recycles.
Let me show you an improved version of the BasePage that I've used successfully in similar situations. It tries multiple ways to detect the language preference and is more resilient to session issues.
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Web

Public Class BasePage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
        Dim language As String = GetCurrentLanguage()
        
        Try
            ' Set the Culture
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo(language)
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo(language)
            
            ' Ensure the session is updated
            If Session("Language") Is Nothing OrElse Session("Language").ToString() <> language Then
                Session("Language") = language
            End If
            
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Log the error and fallback to Arabic
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Culture initialization failed: {ex.Message}")
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("ar")
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("ar")
        End Try
    End Sub
    
    Private Function GetCurrentLanguage() As String
        ' Check multiple sources for language preference in this order:
        ' 1. Session
        ' 2. Query String
        ' 3. Cookie
        ' 4. Browser preference
        ' 5. Default to Arabic
        
        ' 1. Check Session
        If Session("Language") IsNot Nothing Then
            Return Session("Language").ToString()
        End If
        
        ' 2. Check Query String
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("lang")) Then
            Dim queryLang As String = Request.QueryString("lang")
            If queryLang = "en-us" OrElse queryLang = "ar" Then
                Return queryLang
            End If
        End If
        
        ' 3. Check Cookie
        If Request.Cookies("PreferredLanguage") IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim cookieLang As String = Request.Cookies("PreferredLanguage").Value
            If cookieLang = "en-us" OrElse cookieLang = "ar" Then
                Return cookieLang
            End If
        End If
        
        ' 4. Check Browser preference
        If Request.UserLanguages IsNot Nothing AndAlso Request.UserLanguages.Length > 0 Then
            Dim browserLang As String = Request.UserLanguages(0).ToLower()
            If browserLang.StartsWith("en") Then
                Return "en-us"
            ElseIf browserLang.StartsWith("ar") Then
                Return "ar"
            End If
        End If
        
        ' 5. Default to Arabic
        Return "ar"
    End Function
End Class

The key things this does differently:
Checks multiple places for the language setting (session, querystring, cookie, browser preference)
Has proper error handling
Makes sure the session stays in sync
Has some debug logging built in
Also, make sure your web.config has the globalization settings:
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>

One other thing - double check that your App_GlobalResources folder actually made it to the production server with all the resource files. I've seen cases where deployment tools miss these files.
Want me to help you implement any of this? Or we could add some debugging code first to see exactly what's happening with the culture settings in production?

but is it normal for my basepage to work locally and not online ? is it normal that locally i am able to switch between languages but online it always stays arabic ?

also when i put the files online i only put the main dll. i thought that the .resx files are taken in the main dll. and when i saw that the static words that i replaced with resources are appearing correctly online i thought that it was all good. should there be a file on the server regarding the resources ? and how can i know that App_GlobalResources folder actually made it to the production server with all the resource files.
